# how to use action name in jquery ajax instead of insinde the html.actionlink?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to use html.actionlink with no action name, because the action name is in the jquery ajax code.
I know other ways to solve this problem but I want to know how can solve this by html.actionlink.

this is an asp.net-mvc homework with jquery ajax and etc. I want to display students details from database by clicking on their name .

sry for my bad English. tnx

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="direction:rtl">
    <tr>
        نام و نام خانوادگی دانشجو
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>                
                @Html.ActionLink(item.FName + " " + item.LName +
                                    " by JQuery AJAX ", null, null,
                                    new { onclick = "jqueryAjaxDetails(" + item.Id + ")" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

```
<script>
    function jqueryAjaxDetails(sID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/University/_AjaxDetails",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: sID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Details").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failure.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

> I Found a solution by using (a) tag, like this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="jqueryAjaxDetails(@(item.Id))">
   @(item.FName+" "+item.LName + "by JQuery AJAX")
</a>
```

> but how can solve this by @Html.Actionlink????

the html code that @Html.Actionlink produces is :

```html
<a href="/University/AjaxList" onclick="jqueryAjaxDetails(3)">Yeganeh MJanlou by JQuery AJAX </a>
```

this code works but refreshed after clicking because (href) isn't empty.

> how can send an empty ActionName link to the (href)?‍♂️

Comment: Please pass url :`Url.Action("_AjaxDetails", "_AjaxDetails")`

Comment: You can use `Url.Action` (as comment above) as a data- attribute on the actionlink, then the ajax method can read it from the button being pressed.   This is easier to setup using event handling rather than the antiquated `onclick=`.

Comment: TBH there's no point using `Html.ActionLink` here if your action/controller is going to be null.  You're not gaining anything that you can't do with the clearer `<a href='#' onclick=...>@item.FName @item.LName</a>` (and in that case you probably also want it to be `<button>` not `<a>`

Comment: The question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please try this one

For more details click this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

> cshtml page

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="direction:rtl">
    <tr>
        نام و نام خانوادگی دانشجو
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>                
                @Html.ActionLink(item.FName + " " + item.LName +
                                    " by JQuery AJAX ", "_AjaxDetails", "University",
                                    new { onclick = "return  jqueryAjaxDetails(" + item.Id + ")" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Note: your ActionLink also works you need to put only return statement above mention in example.**

**You can't put null values in action and controller name in `Html.ActionLink`**

> Another way in cshtml page

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="direction:rtl">
        <tr>
            نام و نام خانوادگی دانشجو
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>                
                   <a href="#" onclick = "return jqueryAjaxDetails(" + @item.Id + ")">@string.Concat(item.FName," ", item.LName, " by JQuery AJAX")</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

> Javascript code

```
<script>
    function jqueryAjaxDetails(sID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("_AjaxDetails", "University")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: sID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Details").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failure.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note, you can't use server side code (`@Url.Action`) if your javascript is in a .js file.  And all your javascript is in .js files... isn't it...

Comment: Yes, it's true but you can replace it with the value you need to create one variable in layout page after variable declaration include your js file and use javascript variable. like eg `var ourl="@Url.Action("action","controller")"` after this your js file and use `ourl` variable in js file it's work.